# How to delete users from a WordPress MultiSite that stay in the DB?

Tags: multisite, buddypress

How can I tell WordPress to remove deleted users from the database automatically?

I found that I can go into phpMyAdmin > wp_signups and manually remove them, but this would be a hassle for those that admin my site.

I've been spending 2 days looking for plugins, code snippets and hacks but I can't find a way to accomplish this. Can someone please help with this major issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is some commonality between the users you want to delete, you might look at the answers to this question: [Delete all subscribers from wp_users and wp_usermeta a few thousand at a time](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167184/delete-all-subscribers-from-wp-users-and-wp-usermeta-a-few-thousand-at-a-time)

Make sure you have a backup of your database, though, as an error in the selection of the users could delete important users (like admins). If you are going to go this route, test the sql statement first to ensure you didn't select a critical user, or one that you really don't want to delete.

In fact, I'd copy the WP database, and then 'practice' on that database.